# Make BIND DNS server to "remember" the resolved names

Tags: domain-name-system, logging, reverse-dns

I have a corporative VPN server where every client request (the IP address of the server they are accessing) are being logged via an script with tcpdump. However, the logs are not really useful because of a DNS issue.

For example, if someone visits the website www.domain.com, it resolves to the IP 1.2.3.4, but when my script logs that he's accessing the IP 1.2.3.4 and I try to reverse DNS that IP, I usually get something like server28.hostingcompany.com, which seems to be a common behavior.

Is there any way I can make my DNS server to "remember" that the IP 1.2.3.4 resolves to www.domain.com, so when I do a reverse DNS search I get the correct domain name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I really don't think you can achieve what you want in the way that you are trying to do it. The reason is that multiple host names can map to the same IP address. For example if someone on your VPN queries for a.example.com and b.example.com and both resolve to 192.0.2.1. which address should be saved ?

I think you would find it much easier to configure your own DNS resolver that logs the client/query/response and have the VPN server push your resolver address to the clients so they use it.